# What is the etymological difference bewteen ب ر ك and ص ل و‎ roots?

Tags: etymology, semitic-languages, roots

The roots `ب ر ك` (`BRK`) and `ص ل و`‎ (`ṢLW`) shares a common meaning related to the act of blessing.

Is the first one related to the knees, while the later one is rather connected to the notion of eulogy?

---

*(Note: It's not a question about translation, but root origin.)*

Comment: Don't have a complete answer yet, but some data points: Akkadian _karābu_ "praise", _ṣallû_ "pray", Aramaic _ṣəlāʔ_ "pray", Ge'ez _bərəkə_ "kneel to".

Comment: You probably know already that brk is blessing and knees in Hebrew

Comment: @LukeSawczak, yes, I just wanted to determine the etymological difference between them. It might be not knee/eulogy.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the etymological difference". The etymological difference is that they are different roots.

Comment: @ColinFine, I meant the difference of notion. Maybe I mistakenly wrote the question.

Comment: At first I thought "pray" and "bless" are totally different, only the second being transitive, then I saw that صَلَّى is sometimes translated as "bless". But why do you think it is connected to "eulogy"?

Comment: @Metamorphic, I don't recall correctly the "evidences" which lead me to think that, but searching `"ص ل و" eulogy`‎ through the Web does return results. Sadly, no verifiable sources found.

Comment: It isn't really about the sources being verifiable; but rather the sources that come up when I perform that search are talking about [Salawat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salawat), where this root appears, which could be called a eulogy. So if that's the only connection then I'd say there isn't one. Sorry...